# Auto-load Linux Kernel Module

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, driver

I have a Linux driver that can use a driver that exists in the kernel, but only after i manually insert it too. Basically, i insert my driver, then insert the kernel one( its compiled as a module and not built-in), and they can connect to each other.

In order to call the other driver i'm using platform_device_alloc("driver-name", 0), then i allocate the resources for the driver, using the same name and the memory space i need for it, and finally i use platform_device_add.
With this i can connect to the driver and run the probe function with everything i need.

What i want is to just insert my module, and that he recognizes that the other exists in the system, and connect to it without the need to manually insert it.

Thanks for your help and sorry for any English mistakes.

Best Regards

Comment: If your driver uses a symbol exported by the other driver, then your driver will depend on the other driver. If your driver has been installed in the kernel's module directory, and you ran `depmod -a` after installing it, then you can run `modprobe your_driver` (where "your_driver" is the name of your driver module, without the ".ko" extension), and it will auto-load the other driver as a dependency.

Comment: The other driver doensn´t have any exported symbols unfortunately. i link my driver to the kernel directory, i run depmod -a and i insert it. if i modprobe the other driver after, i can connect them both, but i can´t get it to call it without the need to modprobe it.

Comment: Could you edit the question to give more details on how your driver uses the other driver?

Comment: Done as requested.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your driver is creating a platform device and the other driver registers itself as a platform device driver and its probe function gets called with the platform device you created. Does the other driver use the `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE` macro to register its device ID table? This adds aliases to the driver's module information that match the devices it supports. This information is used to auto-load the module when a device with a matching device ID is added to the system.

Comment: Yes it uses, but i have not registered the device i want to automatically load there? if i understood you correctly, you're saying that i should register in the device table the matching device id and it will be auto-loaded?

Comment: In theory, it should auto-load. The device ID table is also used by the other driver when it registers itself as a platform driver - its `struct platform_driver` variable should have a `.id_table` member that points to the its device ID table, and that table should have an entry that matches your device ID.

Comment: In theory it should only autoload if udev is running. Is it?

Comment: The thing is, it shouldn't need the platform driver to be running. if i have the kernel module i need inserted in the system, just by running the device i can access it. But it doesn't load it from the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use a function that has an exported symbol, just like @ian Abbott said. If you don't have exported functions like i did, making a patch for the driver might be the simplest way to get this done!